# Reposition colorbar or subplots

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to get a colorbar to reside to the right-hand-side of a series of four subplots.
I'm using this code but the bar intersects with the last image as shown in this fig [image: problem]

```
ax(1)=subplot(1,3,1);imagesc(stats.mean,[0 1]);colormap(jet(256)); title('mean');
ax(2)=subplot(1,3,2);imagesc(stats.median,[0 1]);colormap(jet(256)); title('median');
ax(3)=subplot(1,3,3);imagesc(stats.std,[0 1]);colormap(jet(256)); title('std');
h=colorbar;
set(h, 'Position', [.8314 .11 .0581 .8150]);
for i=1:3
pos=get(ax(i), 'Position');
set(ax(i), 'Position', [pos(1) pos(2) 0.85*pos(3) pos(4)]);
end;
```

Comment: I'm sure there is a proper way to do this but as a quick fix you could add a 4th subplot and then make `subplot(1,4,4)` an empty image with just the colorbar...

Comment: You are blindly applying the solution proposed in a technical solution named [How do I create a colorbar for my subplots and associate the colorbar with the figure rather than each individual axes in MATLAB 7.7 (R2008b)?](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/solutions/en/data/1-16FPP).

What that solution does is it resizes the sublots and repositions the colorbar. You can simply push the colorbar a bit further with `set(h, 'Position', [.87 .11 .0581 .8150]);`. Note the **.87**.

Comment: @Dan could you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: @OlegKomarov I've tried your solution but still the appear over each other

Comment: Change all your `subplot(1,3,n)` to `subplot(1,4,n)` and then add this line: `subplot(1,4,4);colormap(jet(256));` but it might leave a white empty rectangle :/

Comment: Nobody can help you without knowing what `stats` contains. Also, try to tweak the value till the position of the colorbar is acceptable.

Comment: @Dan :) I don't want empty rectangle

Comment: @OlegKomarov stats is just a vector containing some values like mean, median, standard deviation.

Comment: Just try to tweak numbers in position vector. You need to understand they are just [x, y, width, height] in figure normalized units. For example, `set(h, 'Position', [.9 pos(2) .02 pos(4)]);` And put it after the for-loop. I think @OlegKomarov should put his comments as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest a different approach.

Suppose you are plotting the following:

```
ax(1) = subplot(1,3,1);imagesc(rand(100,1),[0 1]);
ax(2) = subplot(1,3,2);imagesc(rand(100,1),[0 1]);
ax(3) = subplot(1,3,3);imagesc(rand(100,1),[0 1]);
```

I recommend simply resetting the dimension of the third subplot which will be affected by `colorbar` and stretching the figure to include the added colorbar.

```
% Get positions of all the subplot
posa = get(ax,'position');
h    = colorbar;

% Reset ax(3) position to before colorbar
set(ax(3),'position',posa{3})

% Set everything to units pixels (avoids dynamic reposition)
set([ax h],'units','pix')

% Widen figure by a factor of 1.1 (tweak it for needs)
posf = get(gcf,'position');
set(gcf,'position',[posf(1:2) posf(3)*1.1 posf(4)])
```

**The result**

[image]